# How to achieve signal gating with trigger input

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, vhdl, signal, pulse

I am currently working on a project that generates enable pulses of extremely diverse lengths from microseconds to days and under normal operation will start execution under a trigger input.

However, I am trying to add gated triggering so that the pulses will start running when the board turns on but will only output when the trigger is pulled high.

The gated triggering should only output pulses that occur completely during the period of triggering as shown below:

[image]

As you can see if the pulse generator goes high before triggering, then that pulse should not be collected for output. Standard gating logics along the lines of
`if (trigger AND pulse)` do not work and because the pulses can be very long basic lookbehind methods such `if (trigger = '1' AND pulse = '1' AND prev = '0')` (with `prev` being the value of the pulse on the last clock cycle) do not work either.

I would attach code but since none of it achieves the correct outcome I'm not sure it would do much other than confusing.

Comment: How come the 2nd clock pulse from the left doesn't get through?

Comment: Sorry I meant to mention that I believe that's specific to the implementation by the company whose website the image is from. For my situation any pulses on or after the rising edge of the trigger are valid outputs, I will edit the post

Comment: You need to be 100% clear to get a decent answer. If the picture is wrong draw your own.

Comment: Talk about pulse edges either rising or falling please; that's less ambiguous. Easy to be ambiguous here.

Comment: What about a pulse that starts (edge rising) before the trigger edge goes low and potentially gets cut short. Do you in fact need to make a decision about the validity of a pulse i.e. decide at two points in time on both edges being within the trigger pulse? Think hard about this because you could send folk down the wrong trail easily.

Comment: Added my own image that should answer your question, realized how easy it is to create waveforms in quartus!

Comment: I have been working on this for some time, I am 100% sure that as shown at the end of the first trigger pulse a pulse that gets cut off is still okay to be propagated to output

Comment: @JohnB The diagram shows what you want. What's the dynamic range of the gating (min-width vs max-width?) And what's the dynamic range of the pulses to be gated (min vs max, again?) And how quickly must a cutoff pulse be cutoff once the gating terminates? (And yes, I already know the gating dynamic range is huge. I want to know just how huge, exactly.)

Comment: Possibly solved by a D flip-flop with D connected to trigger, clock connected to pulse_in, and asynchronous clear also connected to pulse_in.  (VHDL code for such a flip-flop is very straightforward)

Comment: range for pulses is 2ns to about 9e15 ns (~108 days), trigger will have the same minimum but can be held high as long as necessary; had no luck with DFF and data passed is not the trigger but the pulse so that wouldn’t work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the pulse-gating in your requirement, using a negative level-sensitive latch and an AND gate. Modified version of typical Clock Gating cells found in ASIC libraries.

[image]

If you describe the above circuit in HDL, you should see the expected behavior.

**HDL (System Verilog):**

```
module gated_pulse (

   input  logic trig  ,
   input  logic pb_in ,
   output logic gated 

) ;

logic trig_latched ;

always_latch begin   
   if (!pb_in) begin
      trig_latched = trig ;
   end  
end

assign gated = trig & trig_latched & pb_in ;

endmodule
```

**Simulation:**

[image]

However, there is a catch if you are targetting an FPGA instead of ASIC. Most modern FPGAs don't support latches, and you don't want to infer an inferior one on LUTs. If this is the case, you can 'improvise' the above latch-based circuit using flip-flops on FPGAs.
[image]

**HDL (System Verilog):**

```
module gated_pulse (

   input  logic trig  ,
   input  logic pb_in ,
   output logic gated 

) ;

logic trig_registered ;    
   
always_ff @(posedge pb_in, negedge trig) begin  
   if (!trig) begin
      trig_registered <= 1'b0 ;
   end
   else begin
      trig_registered <= trig ;      
   end
end    

assign gated = trig_registered & pb_in ;

endmodule
```

Comment: In VHDL I believe this would amount to tracking two clock edges in the same process which it cannot synthesize. However, I think it is possible that the FPGA I am utilizing does support latches, do you know if there's a way to verify this?

Comment: @JohnB No, it's a single edge-triggered process. I guess you are not familiar with Verilog semantics. Equivalent to this would be a clocked process in VHDL with an active-low asynchronous reset (trig). `process(clock, trig)`. It synthesised fine on Vivado, it should synthesise on any tool.

Comment: If Latches are available in the vendor libraries for the FPGA you target, you may try out the first approach (but I doubt if it's available at all). Otherwise second one is the simpler one as it would synthesise on any target.

Comment: oh interesting yeah I have never used verilog and assumed pos/neg edge corresponded to rising/falling_edge in vhdl, was slightly confused how you could have tracked two edges in one HDL but not the other, guess it makes sense now